# Remove nearly duplicate lines

Tags: bash, text-processing, uniq

I've got a knotty problem that I can't figure out how to solve.

I have a text file containing a few million lines of text. Basically I want to run `uniq`, but with a twist: If two lines are identical but for a `:FOO` suffix, drop the line that lacks the suffix. But *only* if the lines are otherwise identical. And *only* for `:FOO`, not any other possible suffix.
do *not* want to drop `/usr/bin/delta:FOO`, because the line above isn't identical.

```
red.7
green.2
green.2:FOO
blue.6
yellow.9:FOO
```

I want to delete `green.2`, because the line below is identical but with a suffix. All other lines should be retained unchanged.

[**Edit:** I forgot to mention, the file is already in sorted order.]

My thoughts so far:

- Obviously `uniq` is the tool to do this.
- You can make `uniq` ignore a *prefix*, but never a *suffix*. (This is extremely annoying!)
- I thought perhaps you could pretend that `:` is a field separator, and get `cut` (together with `paste`) to flip the field order. But no, it is apparently impossible to force `cut` to output a blank line if no separator is present.
- My next thought is to go through line by line and output a 1-character prefix depending on the presence or absence of the suffix... but I can't imagine scripting that as a Bash loop being performant.

Any hints?

I may end up just using a *real* programming language to fix this. It seems simple enough to fix in Bash, but I've already wasted quite a lot of time failing to get it to work...

Comment: do you want to keep the version with `:FOO`, the one without it or either? Can you have identical lines that don't have `:FOO` and, if so, what should be done with those?

Comment: @terdon There shouldn't be any lines which are exactly identical. [I should probably go check that though... if there are, something has gone horribly wrong!] I want to keep the longer line with the `:FOO` suffix.

Comment: GNU `uniq` has `--check-chars`, which enables you to ignore suffixes, too.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Seems it doesn't let you ignore the last N characters; it only lets you say "process only the first N characters".

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Correct, just like `--skip-chars` enables you to ignore the first N characters.

Comment: nope, I like @terdon's answer and have deleted my own. It's certainly possible to do in `awk` but it's hard to beat the simplicity of just `sed` and `uniq` and `rev`

Comment: @cas sadly, my solution runs afoul of a bug in (GNU?) `uniq`. While the docs (`info uniq`) claim it uses either tab or space as a field delimiter, it seems to actually use any non-alphanumeric character. You might want to bring back your `awk` approach.

Comment: `uniq` is obviously _not_ the tool for this.  FIFY.  Try `awk` which can much more easily handle context between adjacent lines and has all the text processing regex-foo you need and _your file is already sorted_.  I like unix pipelines as much as the next guy - probably _more_ than the next guy as I'm currently sitting in a Windows shop - but you've got more than one hammer to choose from.

Comment: What if your lines are `ASDF`, `ASDF:FOO`, and `ASDF:FOO:FOO`?

Comment: Regarding the annoying-ness of `uniq`'s inability to ignore suffixes, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/343352/135943

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about joining adjacent pairs of lines, and then using a backreference to find the non-unique prefix?

```
$ sed '$!N; /\(.*\)\n\1:FOO/D; P;D' file
red.7
green.2:FOO
blue.6
yellow.9:FOO
```

Explanation:

- `$!N` - if we are not already at the last line, append the next line to the pattern space, separated by a newline
- `/\(.*\)\n` - match everything up to the newline (i.e. the first of each pair of lines) and save it into a *capture group*
- `\1:FOO` now matches whatever was captured from the first line, followed by `:FOO` (`\1` is a *backreference* to the first capture group)
- `/\(.*\)\n\1:FOO/D` - if the second line of each pair is the same as the first followed by `:FOO`, then `D`elete the first
- `P`rint and `D`elete the remaining line ready to start the next cycle

---

or neater (thanks @don_crissti)

> ```
>  sed '$!N; /\(.*\)\n\1:FOO/!P;D' file
> ```
>
> `N` means there are always two consecutive lines in the pattern space
>   and sed `P`rints the first one of them only if the second line isn't the
>   same as the first one plus the suffix `:FOO`. Then `D` removes the first
>   line from the pattern space and restarts the cycle.

Comment: Sorry @don_crissti maybe the coffee hasn't kicked in yet but I don't understand. The first `D` is deleting the (near) duplicate line, while the second `D` is to make sure we keep a rolling buffer of only 2 lines... or so I thought?

Comment: Ah yes I see thanks - invert the print logic.

Comment: I have literally no idea what on Earth this does, but it works. Very slow, but it works.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid This should be quick, how big is your file ?

Comment: @123 The file is about 72MB.

Answer (score 5):

In the simplest case, to keep the lines without `:FOO`, you could just remove `:FOO` and then pass through uniq:

```
$ sed 's/:FOO$//' file | uniq
red.7
green.2
blue.6
yellow.9
```

If you prefer to keep the `:FOO` lines and assuming that they always come after their non-suffixed brethren, you could try:

```
$ rev file | sed 's/:/ /' | uniq -f1 | sed 's/ /:/' | rev
red.7
green.2:FOO
blue.6
yellow.9:FOO
```

`rev` prints each line from right to left. The `sed` replaces the first `:` with a space so `uniq` can use recognize `FOO` (or `OOF`, in this case) as the 1st field that should be ignored, the next sed puts the `:` back and the final `rev` prints out left to right again.

---

Unfortunately, and despite what its documentation claims, `uniq` doesn't only use space and tab as a field delimiter, but pretty much any non-alphanumeric character:

```
$ printf 'foo/1\nfoo/2\nfoo%%3\nfoo:4\n' 
foo/1
foo/2
foo%3
foo:4
$ printf 'foo/1\nfoo/2\nfoo%%3\nfoo:4\n'  | uniq -f1
foo/1
```

This means the solution above won't work if you have such characters. As an alternative, you could `grep` for all instances of `:FOO` in your file, remove the `:FOO` and feed the result to a new `grep` as a list of patterns to avoid:

```
$ grep -hFxv "$(grep ':FOO' file | cut -d: -f1)" file 
red.7
green.2:FOO
blue.6
yellow.9:FOO
```

Comment: I like this answer. But for some reason, it doesn't appear to work on my actual data, and I can't figure out why...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid can you edit your question with an example of lines it fails for? There's probably something specific to your data. Alternatively, ping me (`@terdon`) in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) and we can debug it there.

Comment: It goes wrong at the `uniq` step. Try with the following lines: `/Foo`, `/Foo/Bar`, `/Foo/Bar/Baz`. After `uniq`, only `ooF/` remains.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid please come into [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat). This solution depends on having `:`, like in your example, what you show above is completely different. Come into chat and we can look into it.

Answer (score 5):

One way in `awk`:

```
awk '$0 != x ":FOO" && NR>1 {print x} {x=$0} END {print}' file
```

Saves the line, then checks at the start of every line that it doesn't contain the saved string + `:FOO`. Print last line as it can't possibly have the next line have `:FOO` as there is none.

Comment: +1.  nice, but try this version instead: `awk '! match($0,x"(:FOO)?$") && NR > 1 {print x} {x=$0} END {print}`.  This version gets rid of ordinary (non- :FOO) duplicate lines too (e.g. two `blue.6` lines).