# Why can uniq ignore leading characters but not ending characters?

Tags: awk, history, uniq

The [POSIX-specified command line tool `uniq`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html) is designed to "report or filter out repeated lines in a file."  Aside from use cases involving the full lines for comparison, there are two options for partial line comparison:

- `-f <number>` to ignore the first `<number>` fields, and
- `-s <number>` to ignore the first `<number>` characters (starting after any ignored fields from `-f`).

What I don't understand is why the feature was never added to `uniq` to allow ignoring *all but the first* `<number>` fields.

A common Awk idiom is:

```
awk '!a[$1]++'
```

which prints only the lines containing the *first appearing* occurrence of their first field.

This has always seemed to me to be very similar to the function of `uniq`.

Of course it's fine for tools to overlap, but is there any historical or UNIX-philosophy based reason not to include the parallel functionality to `-f`, of *only* considering the first ____ fields?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it asks a question like _why is tool xyz as it is?_ - as such the question is not answerable, save that the author of the tool decided it this way and nobody else bothered to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the historical or UNIX-philosophy based reasons (if any) but a few years back someone submitted a feature request (and a patch) on `coreutils` bug list to add that ability to `uniq`. It was eventually rejected:

[`rev | uniq -f | rev` was deemed sufficient](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2011-12/msg00158.html)