# Remove all URLs in a series with the same domain except the last occurrence, in a long list of many URL series

Tags: linux, sed, command-line, grep

I have a problem that I think `sed` is probably perfect for, but I don't know enough about it to figure out how to employ it correctly.

Here's what I have - a file like this, but much longer:

```
https://www.npmjs.com
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rabin
https://www.politico.com/news/magazine/blah/blah
https://www.raspberrypi.org
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/blah
https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/
https://www.reddit.com
https://www.reddit.com/
https://www.reddit.com/r/geology/blah/blah/blah
https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/blah/blah/blah
...thousands more...
```

What I need are just the items in bold, that is there are many series of URLs that share a domain name, and I need the last URL in each series for the whole text file.

So just the ones that have an arrow in front

```
https://www.npmjs.com
->https://www.npmjs.com/package/rabin
->https://www.politico.com/news/magazine/blah/blah
https://www.raspberrypi.org
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/blah
->https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/
https://www.reddit.com
https://www.reddit.com/
https://www.reddit.com/r/geology/blah/blah/blah
->https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/blah/blah/blah
...thousands more...
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: The downvotes can be explained by your not sharing what you have tried so far and just dumping your question onto the community. In any case, I would consider `awk`. Use adequate string functions to determine the domain, then assign the entire line to an associative array indexed by the domain like so: `last_url[domain] = $0`. At the end, print that array. More work would be required to guarantee that the URLs will be printed in the same order as in the input file.

Comment: ... or take a two-pass approach, on the 1st pass saving `FNR` instead of `$0`, on the 2nd pass printing records for which `FNR == last_url[domain]` (this is order-preserving)

Comment: Well the thing is I haven't been able to try anything because I don't know what will work, only that I am sure `sed` probably has some kind arcane syntax I don't know about to make this happen.  I found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281513/remove-nearly-duplicate-lines, but I couldn't get it to work for me.

Comment: FWIW I figured this out using awk:
```
cat urls.txt | gawk -e '{match($0, /(https?:\/\/(?:www.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+?[a-z0-9.]+)/, url)} \

!a[url[1]]++{ \
  b[++count]=url[1] \
} \
{ \
  c[url[1]]=$0 \
} \
END{ \
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){ \
    print c[b[i]] \
  } \
}' > filteredurls.txt
```

Comment: Yikes, that multiline command above got mutilated...basically, the first part of the awk command, `{match($0, /(https?:\/\/(?:www.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+?[a-z0-9.]+)/, url)}`, matches only the domain name on each line (this could easily be written less verbosely and more inclusive, but it worked for my needs) and sets it to a variable.   The rest of the command then loops through all of the lines, collecting the last in each group that matches the domain name in a new array which is then saved to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```bsh
cat input.txt | \
gawk -e '{match($0, /(https?:\/\/(?:www.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+?[a-z0-9.]+)/, url)} \
!a[url[1]]++{ \
    b[++count]=url[1] \
} \
{ \
    c[url[1]]=$0 \
} \
END{ \
    for(i=1;i<=count;i++){ \
        print c[b[i]] \
    } \
}' > output.txt
```

The regular expression could probably be simplified quite a bit, and maybe made to capture more variance in domain names, but for my case it worked fine.   The `awk` command is modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776154/how-to-print-the-last-line-of-each-group-for-long-line-list-in-command-line-usin) answer. (Funny how someone removed the ‘bash’ tag from my question, and the answer that actually helped me was tagged with ‘bash’...

Reflecting on this problem more, I suppose you could also use ask to add the matched domain to the end as a separate “field”, use sort unique to select the last, and then remove the domain “field” at the end, or rather use ask to print only the first “field”, i.e. the original URL, after the sort unique.